# BIOS doesn't recognize hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, bios

I reinstalled my hdd to Linux on other PC since my main PC don't recognize booting USB. But after I added th HDD into my main PC it doesn't recognize it anymore, in BIOS boot options I put "hard drive" as the first option but even so it only boots into EFI shell.

I don't know the BIOS admin password either, I got the PC as a gift and it already had a password set.

Please help, this PC is crucial for my work.

Comment: What bootloader did you use? Did you install for UEFI or BIOS mode?

Comment: Can you explain more please? I am not so well versed in this stuff.

Comment: You mean during the instalation of the Linux?

Comment: Without details about how you installed Linux and your main computer, we can't help you.

Comment: I will try and add the programs I used to install Linux on the HDD

Comment: (As a side comment... what kind of "gift" comes locked down with passwords?)

Comment: Only BIOS was locked with password

Comment: That's not "only", that's quite a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PCs have two common firmware types (BIOS and UEFI), each having its own method of starting the OS from disk. In short, BIOS systems expect a "boot sector" on the disk, while UEFI systems expect to find a specific *.efi file on a specific partition.

Boot from a Linux live CD with this HDD attached (doesn't matter on which computer), then open fdisk, GParted, or some other partitioning tool. Check whether your disk has an "EFI system partition", or a "BIOS boot partition", or neither.

Alternatively, within the EFI shell, use `fs0:` to switch to the disk's EFI system partition (if one exists), and look around using `dir` and `cd` (DOS-like) commands. If that works, then the disk *was* recognized and Linux *is* installed for UEFI systems.

**If your Linux installation is for UEFI systems**

The UEFI boot method allows the disk to have multiple *.efi files (therefore multiple bootloaders from different operating systems). When you install an OS, it records the file name in firmware's NVRAM (the "CMOS memory"). There can be multiple such boot entries; all of them will show up in the firmware's boot menu alongside your disks. (For example, you might see "Windows Boot Manager" among the list of disks.)

The problem is that these boot entries are not stored on the disk but in the firmware – so moving the disk to another PC won't carry them over. When that happens, the new PC will look for the same standard filename only, but won't be able to find custom boot entries that were stored on the old PC.

The solution is to find your bootloader file within the EFI system partition (for Linux it's most likely named "grubx64.efi" or "shimx64.efi"), then copy it to the standard path: `\EFI\boot\bootx64.efi`. You can do this from Linux, Windows, or even from the EFI Shell.

**If your Linux installation is for BIOS systems**

Most UEFI-based PCs can boot from disks installed in BIOS mode, but this is an option (usually labelled "Legacy" or "CSM" mode) and it's common for it to be turned off in the firmware settings.

If you don't have the admin password, you cannot change this option.